# Good yes-or-no questions to ask

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, powers, vampire-the-requiem

In the Mekhet clanbook for Vampire the Requiem, the "Dream Visions" merit allows a character to get a small amount of information about other people and places by asking a single yes-or-no question.

> Dream Visions (•••)
>
> Effect: More than any other clan, the Mekhet dream. And sometimes, between bizarre, gory, awful dreams of death and transformation and blood, they dream of places they haven’t been to and people they haven’t yet met. Sometimes, during some later night, they find themselves going to those places or meeting those people (Nitokris, Vincent Moon and Elisabeta all dreamed of Frances before they met her, for example).
>
> With this Merit, your character can make use of his dream-visions. The first time (and only the first time) he meets another person or visits a place, the player can make a roll of Blood Potency. If it’s a success, the player can ask one (and only one) question about the person or place, which must be phrased so that it can be answered truthfully with “Yes,” “No,” or “Maybe.” The roll can only be made once regarding any individual, and the roll can only be attempted once a scene (meaning that, for example, if the character meets two vampires for the first time, the player must choose which of them to ask the question about, because he won’t ever get the chance to ask about the other).
>
> Note: Though this Merit is not restricted to Mekhet characters, it is found among the Shadows more often than any other clan.

What are some good general questions to ask with this merit, both for characters and for places?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this type of question is a very poor fit for our format as there is no clear correct answer. What you'll end up with is an ongoing list of suggestions, and the community decided a long time a go that list questions do not work. This will mean that the question gets closed to allow you to edit it into something that works a little better.

Comment: Can you narrow down the situation, or type of information you are looking for?  With more specifics, we may be able to provide you with clear, singular answers.  If a list of suggestions is truly what you want, I recommend an RPG forum, such as RPG.net or forum.TheOnyxPath.com.

Answer (score 3):

That depends heavily on your character and story.

If you're hunting down one kindred who committed diablerie against a particular elder, a good question might be "Does this kindred know who committed the act of diablerie against elder Presley?" You shouldn't try fishing one the one Yes in a sea of Nos by asking if he committed the act himself, merely see if he might be the person to pressure for a good lead.

In another, you might be more worried about allegiance to a shadowy organization, whether someone was ever ghoul, etc etc...

The key here is that you can use it to evaluate NPCs or PCs based on what ever binary criteria you think is most important, given your game's plot and political landscape.